# Mongoose: how to insert a new field in Object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to add a new field in the Object, but the old field is removed and inserted a new one. `upsert:true` has no effect.

```
await Model.findOne({userID:message.author.id}, async function(err, user) {
    if (!user.servers_xp[message.guild.id]) {
        await Model.updateOne({userID:message.author.id}, { $set: {
            servers_xp: {[message.guild.id]: {level: 1, curentxp: 0}}
        } }, {upsert:true})
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your $set statement  in the update operation you override the entire server_xp field with a new object: `{[message.guild.id]: {level: 1, curentxp: 0}}`, so your server_xp field will have exactly this object.

Instead, in order to add new fields to the already exists object (server_xp), you should use the dot notation, this way the object will be updated and not overwritten..

Like this:

```
await Model.findOne({userID: message.author.id}, async function (err, user) {
    if (!user.servers_xp[message.guild.id]) {
        let updateObj = {};
        updateObj[`server_xp.${message.guild.id}`] = {level: 1, curentxp: 0};
        await Model.updateOne({userID: message.author.id}, {
                $set: updateObj
            },
    }
});
```

I don't think you need the upsert here. upsert is for new documents (when the filter/query find nothing).